# Access my ReactJS project from other devices in LAN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to access to my ReactJS project from other devices in the LAN network. I already tried 0.0.0.0 for the host address, but I still can't access it.

Comment: Did you try `http://{your_ip}:3000`. Change `3000` also if you have modified the port to provide.

Comment: yep i already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for helps guys, the problem was just firewall, i had to allow port.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using create-react-app boilerplate then after build ie

```
npm run build

serve -s build
```

This will deploy your application and you can access using your IP:port number in your network

Example

http://192.168.1.89:3000

Comment: just built and still same problem.